# Update individual child component

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-react, diode

I'm using Diode 1.0.0 with scalajs-react 0.11.1.

Use case:

- Parent component with list of child components
- Child's model fragment contains `Pot` for asynchronously fetched image
- Child component fetches image when mounted and `Pot` is `Empty`, updating its model fragment

With a naive approach, this causes the following scenario (order of events might be different):

1. Parent is rendered.
2. Child 1 is rendered.

   1. Child 1 dispatches its `GetImageAction`. Model fragment `Pot` is updated to `Pending`.
   2. Model is updated, causing parent to re-render.
   3. All children are re-rendered.
   4. Children 2 … n still have an `Empty` `Pot`, so they trigger their `GetImageAction`s again.
3. Now Child 2 is rendered.

   1. Model is updated, causing parent to re-render.
   2. Etc.

This causes a huge tree of `GetImageAction` invocations and re-renderings.

Some questions:

1. Is it wrong to use the model for this purpose? Would it be better to use component states?
2. How can the re-rendering of the parent be avoided when only the child needs to be updated? I couldn't figure out if / how I can use `shouldComponentUpdate` for this purpose.

---

#### Update 1

I am now adding a React key to each child component. This got rid of the React warning regarding unique keys, but unfortunately didn't solve the issue above. The children get re-rendered, even if their `shouldComponentUpdate` method returns `false`.

From `ParentComponent.render()`:

```scala
  items.zipWithIndex.map { case (_, i) =>
    proxy.connector.connect(
      proxy.modelReader.zoom(_.get(i)), s"child_$i": js.Any).
      apply(childComponent(props.router, _))
  }
```

#### Update 2

I tried implementing the listener functionality in the parent component, but unfortunately the children are still unmounted and re-mounted. Here's the code of my parent component:

```scala
package kidstravel.client.components

import diode.data.{Empty, Pot}
import diode.react.ModelProxy
import diode.react.ReactPot._
import diode.{Action, ModelR}
import japgolly.scalajs.react.extra.router.RouterCtl
import japgolly.scalajs.react.vdom.prefix_<^._
import japgolly.scalajs.react.{BackendScope, ReactComponentB, _}
import kidstravel.client.KidsTravelMain.Loc
import kidstravel.client.services.{KidsTravelCircuit, RootModel}

case class TileProps[T](router: RouterCtl[Loc], proxy: ModelProxy[T])

/**
  * Render sequence of models as tiles.
  */
trait Tiles {

  // The type of the model objects.
  type T <: AnyRef

  /**
    * Override to provide the action to obtain the model objects.
    * @return An action.
    */
  def getAction: Action

  /**
    * Returns the tile component class.
    * @return
    */
  def tileComponent: ReactComponentC.ReqProps[TileProps[T], _, _, _ <: TopNode]

  case class Props(router: RouterCtl[Loc], proxy: ModelProxy[Pot[Seq[T]]])

  class Backend($: BackendScope[Props, Pot[Seq[T]]]) {

    private var unsubscribe = Option.empty[() => Unit]

    def willMount(props: Props) = {
      val modelReader = props.proxy.modelReader.asInstanceOf[ModelR[RootModel, Pot[Seq[T]]]]
      Callback {
        unsubscribe = Some(KidsTravelCircuit.subscribe(modelReader)(changeHandler(modelReader)))
      } >> $.setState(modelReader())
    }

    def willUnmount = Callback {
      unsubscribe.foreach(f => f())
      unsubscribe = None
    }

    private def changeHandler(modelReader: ModelR[RootModel, Pot[Seq[T]]])(
        cursor: ModelR[RootModel, Pot[Seq[T]]]): Unit = {
      // modify state if we are mounted and state has actually changed
      if ($.isMounted() && modelReader =!= $.accessDirect.state) {
        $.accessDirect.setState(modelReader())
      }
    }

    def didMount = $.props >>= (p => p.proxy.value match {
      case Empty => p.proxy.dispatch(getAction)
      case _ => Callback.empty
    })

    def render(props: Props) = {
      println("Rendering tiles")
      val proxy = props.proxy
      <.div(
        ^.`class` := "row",
        proxy().renderFailed(ex => "Error loading"),
        proxy().renderPending(_ > 100, _ => <.p("Loading …")),
        proxy().render(items =>
          items.zipWithIndex.map { case (_, i) =>
            //proxy.connector.connect(proxy.modelReader.zoom(_.get(i)), s"tile_$i": js.Any).apply(tileComponent(props.router, _))
            //proxy.connector.connect(proxy.modelReader.zoom(_.get(i))).apply(tileComponent(props.router, _))
            //proxy.wrap(_.get(i))(tileComponent(_))
            tileComponent.withKey(s"tile_$i")(TileProps(props.router, proxy.zoom(_.get(i))))
          }
        )
      )
    }
  }

  private val component = ReactComponentB[Props]("Tiles").
    initialState(Empty: Pot[Seq[T]]).
    renderBackend[Backend].
    componentWillMount(scope => scope.backend.willMount(scope.props)).
    componentDidMount(_.backend.didMount).
    build

  def apply(router: RouterCtl[Loc], proxy: ModelProxy[Pot[Seq[T]]]) = component(Props(router, proxy))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is due to calling `connect` inside the render method. This will force unmounting/remounting of all child components. It's best to call `connect` for example when the parent component is mounted and then use the result in render.

Alternatively you could skip `connect` altogether and implement change listener inside the parent component directly. When the items collection changes, update the state which forces a re-render updating all components that have changed. Using `shouldComponentUpdate` allows React to determine which components have really changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried to implement the second approach, but unfortunately the problem persists. I updated the question with my current code.

Comment: Looks correct to me. One thing I've noticed causing problems in Scala.js React sometimes is the use of sequences of nodes when a single ReactNode is expected. You could try replacing the `items` with just a single item and see if it makes any difference.